Explicit computation of Čech-cohomology of coherent sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n_A$
$\newcommand{\proj}[1]{\operatorname{proj}(#1)}
\newcommand{\PSP}{\mathbb{P}}$These days I noticed the following result of (constructive) commutative algebra, which I think is probably well known already.
It can probably be useful for doing algebraic computations with a computer algebra system because it reduces the problem of computing the Čech-cohomology to a question of cohomology of a complex of finite $A$-modules. Does anyone know of a reference for it?
Let $X = \proj{S} = \PSP^n_A$ with the graded polynomial ring $S=A[x_0,\dotsc,x_n]$ and a graded $S$-module $M$.
Then the Čech-complex $C^\bullet(M)$ for the covering $\mathfrak{U} = (D_+(x_i))_i$ is built from
$$
C^p(M) = \bigoplus_{i_0 < \dotsb < i_p} M_{(x_{i_0}\cdot \dotsb \cdot x_{i_p})}
$$
with the differentials
$$
\delta_C^p((m_{i_0,\dotsc,i_p}))_{i_0,\dotsc,i_{p+1}} = 
\sum_{\nu = 0}^{p+1} (-1)^\nu \rho^\nu_{i_0,\dotsc, i_{p+1}}(m_{i_0,\dotsc, \widehat{i_\nu}, \dotsc, i_{p+1}})
$$
where $\rho^\nu_{i_0,\dotsc,i_{p+1}}$ is the canonical map
$$
M_{(x_{i_0} \cdot \dotsb \widehat{x_{i_\nu}} \dotsb \cdot x_{i_{p+1}})} \to M_{(x_{i_0} \cdot \dotsb \cdot x_{i_{p+1}})}.
$$
Further we define a complex $D^\bullet_d(M)$ of $A$-modules by
$$
D^p_d(M) = \bigoplus_{i_0 < \dotsb < i_p} (M_{(p+1) d}^{(i_0,\dotsc, i_p)} = M_{(p+1) d})
$$
with the differentials
$$
\delta^p_D((m^{(i_0,\dotsc,i_p)}))^{(i_0,\dotsc,i_{p+1})} =
\sum_{\nu = 0}^{p+1} (-1)^\nu x_{i_\nu}^d m^{(i_0,\dotsc, \widehat{i_\nu},\dotsc, i_{p+1})}.
$$
There are obvious morphisms
$$
D^p_d(M) \xrightarrow{\alpha^p_d} C^p(M), \quad 
\alpha \left(m^{(i_0,\dotsc,i_p)}\right) = m^{(i_0,\dotsc,i_p)}/(x_{i_0} \cdot \dotsb \cdot x_{i_p})^d
$$
which give rise to a morphism of complexes
$$
\alpha^\bullet_d: D^\bullet_d(M) \to C^\bullet(M).
$$
Then we have the following
Proposition
For every finitely generated $S$-module $M$ and for all $d \geqslant d_0$ for a certain $d_0$ the morphism $\alpha^\bullet_d$ induces isomorphisms
$$
h^p(\alpha^\bullet_d): h^p(D^\bullet_d(M)) \xrightarrow{\sim}h^p(C^\bullet(M))
$$
of all cohomology groups.
It can be proved easily by considering exact sequences $0 \to N \to E \to M \to 0$ and noticing that if the proposition holds for two of the modules in the sequence, then also for the third. So we can reduce to $M = S(k)$ and solve this case by considering the Koszul-complex $K_\bullet(x_0^d,\dotsc,x_n^d)$.

MathJax note: MathJax doesn't eat whitespace as aggressively as TeX does, so it's easy accidentally to force your post to start with several blank lines—for example, by having the dollar sign that ends the "preamble" be on its own line, rather than immediately adjacent to the first character of the post.  I edited to fix this blank space.
